# Elastic Search gradle fails to build shadowJAR

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, shadowjar

I am new to Elastic Search. I downloaded the sources last night so that I can compile and take a look at the code, perhaps to contribute if I feel I can do so. I almost got it compiling on OpenSuse 15.2 except that I keep running against the following error concerning sql-cli:ShadowJar:

```
5:36
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':x-pack:plugin:sql:sql-cli:shadowJar'.
> No such property: count for class: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.ServiceFileTransformer
5:37
```

Anyone has any idea? I looked at the reported bugs section and I've searched online but I don't see any mention of similar problems